# Simulate printing for ePOS-print iOS sdk

Tags: ios, printing, simulator, epson

I am using epos sdks for printing in my app. I don't have printer to check the exact output of the printed bill. So is there any way to simulate the output without printer by using epos iOS SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please download the sdks from the following location https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=4768&scat=50&pcat=7

```
1. Unzip the downloaded file(if it not done automatically) and go to the javascript folder.
2. Unzip "ePOS-Print_Sample_SDK_V5.0.1E" and check for the folder "editor".
3. Open the folder and right click on the 'index.html' file and open it using any browser.
4. Use the edit to enter the input and check the output in preview tab.
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use EPSON's ePOS XML Editor. I've published the source code for it in a public repo and added a Github Page so it's easier to find and use.

You can find it here: https://franciscohanna.me/epson-epos-xml-editor/.

In the editor, you can drag and drop elements and use the Preview tab to have an approximate preview of the print.